# How do I fill down checkboxes linked to cells and have the cell references transpose?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I added a checkbox to my excel sheet, and I go to properties and it lets me link it to a cell. I want to do a 'fill down' to get a column of checkboxes, but so all the checkboxes are linked to their own cell.

However when I do a fill, all cells end up linked to the first cell. Checking one checkbox checks them all.

I am not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution from [this website](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/01/14/click-a-cell-to-check-yes-or-no/):

- Press Alt+F11 to open Visual Basic
- Click Insert → Module (because [the website](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2014/01/14/click-a-cell-to-check-yes-or-no/) says you should paste it to a regular module, so I copied how to do this from [here](https://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQYpRBJEH8w))
- Paste the following code into the text box of the newly created module:

  ```
  Sub LinkCheckBoxes()
  Dim chk As CheckBox
  Dim lCol As Long
  lCol = 2 'number of columns to the right for link
  For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
     With chk
        .LinkedCell = _
           .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, lCol).Address
     End With
  Next chk
  End Sub
  ```
- In the Excel window, click on View → Macros, select `LinkCheckBoxes`, click Run

This will link each checkbox to the cell two positions to the right of it (hence the parameter `2` in the code).

Answer (score 0):

Without any programming with VBA, Right Click each checkbox and edit its FormControl property to use a different cell.

Comment: There are like 200 checkboxes...